# GA Management API, Insert filter: lowercaseDetails.field not valid?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am working on a web tool to insert filter through management API.

When creating lowercase function, I used strings such as 'Hostname' or 'hostname' in lowercaseDetials.field, but I get an 400 error and the detail is 'lowercaseDetails.field is required'. Seems that whatever I passed on was not in the correct format?

Anyone has an idea how I should specify this 'field'? I imagined it should just be the string in the option list in GA? I can't see anything in google developer docs

```
var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.filters.insert(
    {
      'accountId': accountId,
      'resource': {
        'name': filterName,
        'type': 'LOWERCASE',
        'lowercaseDetails': {
          'field': "Hostname"
        }
      }
    });
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it should be all capitalized, also, a space should be replaced with an underscore.